# Как добавить к проекту библиотеку quartz.net

Tags: c#

Хочу написать программу, которая бы выполнялась в определенный час, т.е. мини-планировщик. Стандартный не устроил. Нашел библиотеку `quartz.net`, добавить ее нужно с помощью NuGet. Поставил себе NuGet на MS VS 2010 express edition, но что дальше делать не понял. Добавил ссылку на библиотеки Qartz, но проект их не видит. Может кто работал с этой библиотекой и наставит меня на путь истины? И если с кодом поможет - нужно запускать приложение в определенный час, буду очень признателен. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: А как именно вы добавили ссылку? Если добавить ссылку правильно, в проекте библиотечные функции должны быть доступны.

---
А вы рекомендации [отсюда](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/download.html) выполнили? Какой результат?

Comment: Я скопировал библиотеку в папку с проектом, и добавил ссылку на нее в MS VS. И при using Quartz получаю что ссылки нет

Comment: @Николай Мартынов: Повторюсь: _как именно_ вы добавили ссылку? На что именно? Куда добавили?

Answer (score 1):

С NuGet'ом вообще все прозрачнее некуда - он сам все за вас делает, поскольку он снимает с вас труд искать библиотеки, помещать их куда-то и добавлять на них ссылки. Если у вас возникла трудность в работе с этим менеджером, то имеет смысл почитать  документацию, коей навалом. Так или иначе, в двух словах (учитывая, что сам NuGet вы по вашим же словам установили):

1. Открываете консоль управления пакетами Nuget. **Tools => Nuget Package Manager => Package Manager Console**
2. Выполняете в консоли команду **Install-Package Quartz**, после чего Nuget делает всю работу по добавлению библиотеки за вас
3. Добавляете в код **using Quartz**
4. PROFIT (только что проверил на МЫ 2013, работает. Полагаю, на МЫ 2010 тоже встанет без проблем)

Примеров работы с библиотекой в сети вагон и тележка. Полагаю, найти их не сложно